# mongodb regular expressions matching

Tags: regex

i am having these kind of strings

```
"abc?ref1=app";

"abc?ref1=app&xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
```

where xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx is some string...

i want to write regular expression which should only match `"abc?ref1=app"` types of strings and should not match any other string like `"abc?ref1=app&xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"` ..i mean it should only and only match `"abc?ref1=app"` type of strings...

i have written some thing like this `/abc\?ref1=app/` ..but this will also match `"abc?ref1=app&xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"`

please tell me how to write regular expression which will only match `"abc\?ref1=app"`

Answer (score 1):

You do not even need regex here, since mongoDB uses lexographical comparison
a simple

{ `"myStr" : { $lte : "abc?ref1=app" }`

where myStr is your db key
will work
a string like `abc?ref1=app&xyz`  would be counted as greater than your query.

Answer (score 0):

Add an end-of-line ($) token

```
abc\?ref1=app$
```